# Прозрачный IDE Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Как сделать прозрачный фон в VS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте установить это расширение
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=s-nlf-fh.glassit